# SilverLight: HyperLinkButton is there any other way to pass arguments to the Click function besides using Tag?

Tags: silverlight, hyperlink, arguments

I have this in the XAML:

```
   <HyperlinkButton Tag="{Binding Href}" Click="lbImage_hyperlink">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Href}" Height="40" Width="40" Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                               Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,-1,0" />
                            </HyperlinkButton>
```

in the code behind I use the Click function:

```
  private void lbImage_hyperlink(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HyperlinkButton hlbTemp = sender as HyperlinkButton;
        ImageSource imageSource = (ImageSource)hlbTemp.Tag;
        Preview.Source = imageSource;
    }
```

How can I take advantage of the RoutedEventArgs? Or any other way beside using Tag?

Thanks

SimpleCode

Answer (score 0):

`NavigateUri` is a DependencyProperty therefore you can bind it to whatever you so desire on your ViewModel or other object representation if you are not following an MVVM pattern. Keep in mind it accepts a `Uri` so make sure the property you bind to is a `Uri` not a `String`. If you want to use a `String` make use of an `IValueConverter`.

```
<HyperlinkButton NavigateUri="{Binding UriOnViewModel}" Click="lbImage_hyperlink">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Href}" Height="40" Width="40" Stretch="UniformToFill" 
                               Cursor="Hand" Margin="0,0,-1,0" />
                            </HyperlinkButton>
```